# How to get the iPhone 4.x simulator in xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have installed xcode 4.2. In toolbar, schemes section, shows only iPhone/iPad 5.0 simulator.
what i have to do in order to see other platforms simulator like 3.0, 4.2 etc.

Comment: Hey! If my answer was helpful, please accept it. Otherwise, please provide more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Preferences->Downloads, there you can download older versions of the Simulator. It only offers 4.3 though, i doubt that older ones are available for Xcode 4.2.

**Edit:** There seems to be no official information about this but many users in the Dev Forums claim that older simulators are indeed unsupported with Xcode 4.2.

Comment: That's odd... My installation has options for a simulator for iOS 4.0 - 4.1, and a simulator for iOS 3.0 - 3.2.2 to be installed

Comment: That are not simulators, that are debugging symbols - support for debugging on devices running iOS 3.x or 4.0-4.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't by any easy way. I was hopping the debugging symbols package in Preferences -> Downloads would do it, but no.

The alternative is here: [Xcode 4.3 and iPhone Simulator 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342701/xcode-4-3-and-iphone-simulator-4-2)