# Xcode 4.3 and iPhone Simulator 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

Is there a way to install iPhone Simulator 4.2 in Xcode **4.3** for Lion?
I only can find how to install it in Xcode 4.2, but not Xcode 4.3 for Lion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have found a way to install iPhone simulator 4.2 to Xcode 4.3:

Follow the [instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31412/how-can-i-install-iphone-simulator-4-2-on-xcode-4-2) by Parth Bhatt, but install the simulator in a temporary folder ('Developer' folder doesn't exists in Xcode 4.3).

Once installed, go to `<tmp_dir>/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`, and you'll find a file named "iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk".

Open a new Finder window and go to `/Applications` and right-button on Xcode, select show the package contents, navigate to `/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`, you will see a .sdk files, one for each iPhone simulator installed in Xcode.

Drag the "iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk" file from your temporary folder and drop inside SDKs folder of Xcode package.

Restart Xcode and that's all (you can delete the temporary folder).

If your project has a Deployment target to 4.2, you'll have the 4.2 simulator available.

Comment: If you want to save time and a lot of disk churn, you can extract the iPhoneSimulator42 package with Pacifist (it’s in `Essentials`:  `iPhoneSDKMeta`: `iPhoneSDK4_2`: `iPhoneSimulatorSDK4_2.pkg`), and then copy the same `iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk` folder nested inside `Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` into Xcode’s bundle.

Comment: I installed older simulator 4.3 from Xcode | Preferences |Download.  But it doesn't show up in dropdown list near debug run button.  I still can only debug run in simulator 5.1 or 5.0.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @GeorgeW you need to set 4.3 ad your development target.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @cbowns. Saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Preferences -> Downloads tab -> Components tab" and install what You need. At the moment it lets me download 4.3 and 5.0 simulators.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible. You can just download and install the SDK provided by Apple

Comment: No, it's because apple doesn't want to offer the download.  Download old xcode's to get old SDK's

Comment: CodaFi, Apple did not provide ability to download iPhone Simulator 4.2 in previous Xcodes too. But anyway you had a way to do it. So, what changed? My suggestion - sandbox

Comment: If you download iOS SDK 4.3, you can find iOS 4.2 simulator, but the Xcode version will be 3.2. see this link http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.in/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html