# Is it possible to add support of iOS 5.1 simulator in OS X 10.9?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

Xcode 4.4.1 crashes in OS 10.9 when I switch to xib. file in my project.
Log shows that problem is connected to iOS 5.1 simulator.
Is it possible to add support of iOS 5.1 simulator in OS X 10.9?
If it is possible how can I solve this problem?

1. install later Xcode and copy SDK from older Xcode? (will it work?)
2. do something only with Xcode 4.4.1? (any way I need to install Xcode 5, but I need Xcode 4.4.1 too)

Comment: Yeah you used to be able to make a copy of the SDK from an older installation and copy it into the Xcode app bundle.  Not sure if it still works or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342701/xcode-4-3-and-iphone-simulator-4-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540739/xcode-5-0-1-and-ios-5-1-simulator-issue

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you can specify which version of iOS the simulator shall use.
Preferences > Downloads

As far as I know in it is only possible to go back to iOS6.0 and iOS6.1 when using Xcode5.
This is related to Xcode and not OSX.

Answer (score 0):

1. It will not work because in Xcode 5 under OS X v10.9 the iOS 5 simulator is not available. (I've tried it)

Comment: This does not quite answer the question, does it? Is there any viable solution for the problem?